# SQL server- DTS package: minimum rights

Tags: sql-server, dts

I created a DTS package.

Someone else wants to be able to save it after modifications but he is getting error:
only sysadmin and DTS creator can save versions of DTS.

I have given him dtsadmin rights in msdb and he has db_owner rights in all the Databases which link to this DTS package.

I dont want to give him sysadmin rights.

What is the minimum level access I should grant him so that he can save changes to this DTs package from Enterprise manager?

Regards
Manjot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction; there's a lot of possible security options for DTS, and this article defines them pretty well.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282463/